# Suggestioned packages for checkstyle illegal imports

Tags: java, checkstyle

I'm writing a java webapp based on Spring. Any suggestions for what I might add to the illegalPkgs import declaration for? I just added `javax.transaction.Transactional` to the banned list because it messed me up when I was refactoring I accidentally used the `@Transactional` annotation from javax instead of the one from Spring and it broke my JPA transactions. Looking for other packages or specific classes I should ban proactively!

What I have so far

```
<property name="illegalPkgs" value="sun, java.sql, java.awt, javax.swing, javax.transaction.Transaction"/>
```

Comment: Only you can decide what packages are illegal or not. It is based on your requirements and styles for your project.

Comment: Such a list would be useful if each entry has a good rationale, like you did with @Transactional.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apart from the default `sun` or, as some prefer for clarity, `com.sun,sun`, the [IllegalImport](https://checkstyle.org/config_imports.html#IllegalImport) check is mostly helpful for checking project-specific rules.

For example, if you want to make sure that everybody uses log4j as logging framework, you might add `java.util.logging,org.apache.commons.logging` to the list. Possibly more, as this would depend on how far you have control over your transitive dependencies.

Another example is, if you want to constrain the use of reflection to certain parts of your code base, you might add `java.lang.reflect,org.reflections`.

Using just *IllegalImport* will not gain you much though. You will probably need other checks, like *IllegalType*, *IllegalInstantiation*, or [ImportControl](https://checkstyle.org/config_imports.html#ImportControl), too. In general, using Checkstyle for this is not a silver bullet anyway.